# Customize form in InfoPath 2010 with Custom fields into SharePoint 2010 List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, custom-fields, infopath2010

In my SharePoint List I have a custom field which is a filtered lookup.

The thing is that I would like to customize my form in InfoPath 2010 for that list, but I can't because I've got a custom field into it. When I'm trying to edit the list form from SharePoint I get the following error message in InfoPath :

> "The SharePoint list form can't be customized with InfoPath because
>   fields of an unsupported data type are marked as required, or because
>   fields are corrupted. In SharePoint, try deleting the columns or
>   editing the column properties to remove the required attribute. -
>   Items (FilteredLookupField)"

This is normal, because it's not supported but is there a way that I could customize that form in InfoPath? If not, tell me how I could do it.

Many thanks.

P.S. I can't put any images yet. I don't have enough rep. ; )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, InfoPath will not help you there. You can however try to accomplish it in SharePoint Designer as it also offers a customizable, XSLT-based form control you can use.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will be looking at that.